# set Banner Position in LayoutParams

Tags: android

i try to add adView banner in my oncreate .
but it go to left top of screen and i use most paramter to change position to center button but it not move any why.

```
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams  adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            adView = new AdView(this);
            adView.setToken("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

            addContentView(adView, adParams);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with 'gravity' parameter:

```
 FrameLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new  
 FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        , LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 adParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

 adView = new AdView(this);
 adView.setToken("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
 addContentView(adView, adParams);
```

Comment: but adParams dont have gravity properties.gravity cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: try with FrameLayout params